# no such table: SQLite in VB.net: UWP

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, sqlite, uwp

I'm new to EF Core and SQLite and I followed the steps at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/uwp/getting-started. Everything works just fine in C#, however when translating it to VB, I get the following exception:

```
Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException: 'SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: Blogs'.'
```

I've tried changing the "Data Source=Blogging.db" to an absolute path, but if I do I get

`Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException: 'SQLite Error 14: 'unable to open database file'.`'

This is what I am using right now (in the context):

```
Protected Overrides Async Sub OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder As DbContextOptionsBuilder)
        Dim AssetsFolder As StorageFolder = _
             Await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("Assets")

        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(String.Format("Data Source={0}", _
                                 Path.Combine(AssetsFolder.Path, "blogging.db")))
End Sub
```

And in the App.xaml.vb:

```
Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    Using db = New BloggingContext()
        db.Database.Migrate()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Any help would be much appreciated. If you require more info, please let me know and I'll gladly provide it.

Crix

Comment: Did you create the `Blogs` table? SQLite EF provider does not support migrations out of the box. Otherwise you are opening a wrong file. Also, if you need a SQLite migration library you can use this package https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite.EF6.Migrations/

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I did run 'Add-Migration MyFirstMigration' which (hopefully) created the blogs-table for me. So I have got a 'Migrations'-Folder with three Migration files in it.

Comment: Uninstall your app from your system (start -> right click your app -> uninstall ) and then run through VS.

Comment: Still the same result. It's so weird that it works on C# but doesn't on vb.

Comment: I've uploaded the project just in case someone would want to have a look at it. Dont mind the name - i just got really frustrated after a while. Thanks to everyone who helped so far. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6bWtt07nctTbkNZMFNveGZhTHc

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be due to the created .cs files. When you convert the three files to .vb files, the desired tables are created and an entry is created in the EFMigrationsHistory table. I have manually converted the following files from cs to vb:

1. 20170819131117_Inital.cs
2. 20170819131117_Inital.Designer.cs
3. DB_ModelModelSnapshot.cs

And the cs files taken from the project and the vb added. If someone now knows how to run the add-migration command for vb, that would be very helpful.